# Beginning Clojure without Java experience - how to best organise and run projects?

Tags: clojure

Apologies in advance for the somewhat discursive nature of this clump of related questions; I hope the answers will be a useful resource for newcomers to Clojure.

I have just begun to learn Clojure, motivated in part by [this](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html) essay. I'm not a professional developer but I have several decades of programming experience (ARexx, VB/VBScript/VBA, then Perl and daily use of R starting in 2011). My platform is Windows 7 64-bit. I'm using Emacs 24.3, cider 20131221 and Leiningen 2.3.3 on Java 1.7.0_45 Java Hotspot 64-bit server. I have bought [Clojure Programming](http://www.amazon.com/o/ASIN/B007Q4T040) and the [Clojure Data Analysis Cookbook](http://www.amazon.com/o/ASIN/B00BECVV9C) and dipped into both. I have found them promising but I am getting lost in the detail.

Obviously the thing to do is to get stuck in and experiment with code exercises and small tasks, but the immediate problem for me has been the complexity of structuring, organising and even just plain running projects in Clojure. With R I can get away with a file of plain text containing the bulk of the code, perhaps with one or two others containing common functions for larger projects.

Clojure is *very* different and with no experience in Java I am struggling to put the pieces together. Clojure Programming has a whole chapter on organising and building projects, but it is so comprehensive that conversely I'm finding it difficult to tease out the information relevant to me now. I guess I'm looking for something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285437/a-gentle-tutorial-to-emacs-swank-paredit-for-clojure) on Swank, but the tools seem to have moved on since then. So here goes.

1. Leiningen produces amongst other things a `project.clj` file that contains the project definition and dependencies. I think I get this. Can I use this file for code not related to the definition, below the `defproject`, or is it best to leave this untouched and have the code itself in different `clj` file(s)?
2. If the answer is to leave the `project.clj` file alone, how is the relationship between that and other files established? Is it simply that all the `clj` files in the project folder are counted part of the project?
3. How do I define the main code file, the 'entry point' of the project? Let's say I have `project.clj` and `main.clj` with some helper functions in `common.clj` - how are the relations between these three files defined? I can call functions from `main.clj` but how does the project know that main is the core of the project if/when I package the project into an uberjar?
4. If I have a number of `clj` files, what is the best way to import functions? I have read about `require` and `use` (and `import` and `refer` and...) but I don't fully understand the difference and those two keywords are difficult to search for. The examples for REPL in the Clojure Data Analysis Cookbook most often opt for `use`. I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062737/idiomatic-approach-for-structuring-clojure-source-code) but it was a little over my head.
5. This is more tool-specific, but as Emacs seems to be widely used it seems fair to ask: what's a good workflow to run small bits of code given (say) the `main.clj` example given above? Currently I just open the `main.clj` file in Emacs, do an `M-x cider-jack-in` to establish the REPL, experiment in the REPL, then when I want to try something I select the whole buffer and select `Eval region` from the CIDER menu (`C-c C-R`). Is this standard operating procedure or utterly misguided?
6. Is there a convention for defining namespaces? I think I understand that namespaces can cover multiple `clj` files and that `ns` is used to define the namespace. Should I explicitly define the namespace (at the beginning of) every file of code? Clojure Programming has some recommendations but I'm interested in input from other users.
7. Clojure programming says to "Use underscores in filenames when namespaces contain dashes. Very simply, if your namespace is to be `com.my-project.foo`, the source code for that namespace should be in a file located at `com/my_project/foo.clj`". (EDIT as explained in [this useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4451693/952708) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223369/952708)). This restriction would never have occured to me. Are there any other gotchas with regard to naming namespaces and variables? R frequently uses dots in variable names but I guess given the Java connection that dots should generally be avoided?

Comment: Paul Graham is a damn good writer indeed. I barely know Common Lisp, but I tried to learn it because of his texts. "Revenge of the Nerds" is also great.

Comment: I think the basic naming style for variables is to use dashes everywhere, like ``example-variable``. Also, dynamic vars should be named like this: ``*dynamic-var*``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, don't put actual code in there unless you know what you are doing (e. g. generate the version number for defproject from the local git repository like in the repositories of juxt)
2. The project.clj is simply one big parameter to Clojures build tool leiningen. See an example here https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj. For example, you could specifiy a different source directory than `src` in the `:source-path`.
3. Default is the `-main` function in `project.core`, but you can specify various different configurations in the `project.clj`.
4. `require` is preferred. `:use` imports all publics of a namespace unless you use it in conjunction with `:only`. Require let's you use an alias for an entire namespace with `:as`, but you can have the same effect from `use` with `:only` using `:refer`. Notice that in ClojureScript `:use` without `:only` is not even allowed.
5. This is normal. There are other combos like e.g. `C-c C-k` to reload the entire file of the buffer. If you find yourself entering too many forms into a REPL and would rather edit them in a separate buffer https://www.refheap.com/22235.
6. I like to experiment trying to name namespaces in in verbs rather than nouns, e. g. I prefer `myproject.parse`, `myproject.interpret`, over `myproject.parser`, `myproject.interpreter` etc. But that's a question of personal style. EDIT: Yes, explicitly define the naming of the namespace by its filename and the `ns` form at the beginning of the source file. It is unusual to have multiple source-file defining one namespace.
7. Afaic this is the only caveat regarding naming of namespace. You can hardly know it in advance.

I like your "worried" approach. You will (hopefully) find out that Clojure and especially Leiningen are almost nonsense-free in terms of these questions.

Regarding REPL use: I saw your comment under @Mars answer that you want to use a REPL in a fashion that you can re-use what you are entering. Two things:

1. Dynamic development is awesome, allowing you to test small components or functions interactively without the need to run an entire program written for that purpose.
2. If you find your self entering huge forms at the REPL that you intend to de-/recompose into functions or tests later, I recommend editing them in a seperate clj file that is not part of the project source (i. e. not in a namespace). You can then use [this](https://www.refheap.com/22235) Emacs hack to eval forms from a Clojure buffer in the REPL. Ideally split your Emacs in two windows (C-x 3) with the nrepl buffer on one side and your .clj on the other side. Then use `C-x C-.` from within the clj file to have the form at point pasted into the nrepl and be evaluated. Installation instructions are at the link (and your .emacs file usually resides in the home directory).

Answer (score 1):

@Igrapenthin's answers are great.  Here are a few other thoughts.

On namespaces, [this tutorial](http://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html) is great.

Just to clarify re #2: No, don't just put the .clj files anywhere under the project.  They have to be under src/, or in whatever directories are listed (as strings) in the vector after `:source-paths` in project.clj, if that entry exists.  Then strip off that initial path when you're making your namespace names.  This drove me crazy until I figured it out.  (People who know better, please correct me if something here isn't right.)

One #3, you need Igraphenthin's answer, but why not just start by evaluating expressions in the REPL?  I've been working on a project on and off for weeks, and it does a lot, but my `-main` function still doesn't do anything.  I just run whatever parts I'm working on.  Well, you're used to languages with fully operational prompts--you decide.

EDIT: Whether or not you define the `-main` function to do anything, you can also put `:use` or `:require` keywords in the `ns` statement that defines the namespace for that same file.  These will automatically get invoked when you start the REPL with `lein repl`, and so whatever you have made available through the `ns` keywords will be available at the REPL.  That way, you have your previous work available, but you can play around with it in different ways in the REPL.  (Also, if you don't like the default name for the file that's automatically loaded, you can redefine it in project.clj with `:main`.  Igraphenthin alluded to that.)

Comment: So if the namespace name be `foo-bar.clj` the path for the file would be `/user/code/clojure/myproject/src/foo_bar.clj`? Thanks for the tutorial link, it is useful. I am also using the REPL but I'd like to be saving and reusing what I'm doing so that I can refresh my memory for future sessions.

Comment: @SlowLearner I addressed this issue in my answer.

Comment: @SlowLearner, the answer is implict in Igraphenthin's detailed response, but: Yes.  I also added an edit to my answer in response to your comment about the REPL.